# Does The Sympathetic Nervous System Increase or Decrease Urination?

Tags: human-biology, neuroscience, physiology, psychology

According to my book:

> Sympathetic nervous system stimulation, leads to the release of Norepinephrine(Noradrenaline), priming the body for the "Fight or Flight" response.

It is also stated that:

> The effect of sympathetic stimulation is to maintain urinary continence.

But if sympathetic stimulation results in urinary continence, why do we urinate more when afraid or nervous?

---

I've read [this quesion](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/28578/why-do-we-urinate-more-when-we-are-nervous), but the accepted answer states that adernaline(epinephrine) is released (*not norepinephrine*) and doesn't provide evidence to support why does adernaline result in more urination.

Comment: Are you sure that we urinate more when we are nervous?

Comment: I think that is what is common, you urinate when you are afraid.. @user438383